# MySQL unable to change character_set_*

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm trying to change character_set_* from latin1 to utf8 in /etc/my.cnf.

I've tried all of the following:

```
character_set_server=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
default-character-set=utf8
default_character_set=utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

But all of them get `unknown variable XXX`. However, after deleting these, only `character_set_database` and `character_set_server` remain latin1.

I noticed there isn't utf.xml in `character_sets_dir`. Does it matter?

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

Comment: Make sure the statement is in the [mysql] section of my.ini.

Comment: Yes, in [mysql] section of my.cnf

Comment: Now I have to face the problem again. And I think I just did the same things, but it finally works, and I don't know why..

Comment: Maybe you didn't restart the server the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

in `[mysqld]` section